# Wordpress Google XML Sitemaps Plugin - Other Plugins Deleted

Tags: xml, wordpress, sitemap

I just uploaded the google xml sitemaps plugin after doing some SEO work and activated it...poof...after submitted the xml maps ALL of my other plugins were deleted from my Wordpress site.  Kinnnnda a huge deal.

Has anyone else run into this issue?  Any ideas?

Comment: Also note, they are showing up in the FTP...and when trying to reinstall I'm getting an error ...'The package could not be installed. No valid plugins were found.'  ...for every plugin

Answer (score 0):

PHP virus with a line of code inputed to the top of each .php file.  Plugins showed up when I edited each .php file deleting the viral code.  It is present throughout the site though so I was recommended a complete reinstallation.  New Wordpress, Fresh Theme, Fresh Plugins.

I read the issue was with the zend framework...no clarity on that tho.